# How to use flatMapMerge from kotlin flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have these piece of code and I want it to make it more optimal

I guess I can use kotlin-flow's  flatMapMerge 
but I don't think how should I convert my code to flow

```
  val quiries = listof("s","b","s","g","d","r","t")
    quiries.map { query ->
      viewModelScope.launch {
        val results = fetchColumns(query)
        resultMutableData.postValue(results)
      }
    }
```

and fetchColumns() are suspended functions 
I am thinking maybe I need to have flows of queries ???? what is the way of using flatMapMerge()?

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html

Comment: I would suggest changing the title of the question to something that over the top describes the problem

Answer (score 6):

Try using something like this:

```
listOf("s","b","s","g","d","r","t").asFlow()
    .map { fetchColumns(it) }
    .onEach { resultMutableData.postValue(it) }
    .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Since you don't switch onto another flow, there is no need for any of `flatMap*` functions, just `map` will be enough. Moreover, `map` parameter is already declared as `suspend`, so you won't block your thread. 
But `map` operator was designed to process data sequentially, so these transformations won't be run in parallel. To achieve parallel processing, a workaround using `flatMapMerge` can be used:

```
listOf("s","b","s","g","d","r","t").asFlow()
    .onEach { println("onEach: $it") }
    .flatMapMerge {
        flow {
            emit(fetchColumns(it))
        }
    }
    .onEach { resultMutableData.postValue(it)) }
    .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: but in this case  map work sequentially ,yes? 
What if I want to  start fetching concurrently

Comment: @ArturA You're right, map function is designed to process data sequentially. [There is](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1147) still an ongoing consideration about adding parallel versions of sequential operators at the coroutines repository.. There has been suggested a solution to make map operation parallel, I've updated the answer with that solution.

Comment: @ Stanislav Shamilov thanks 
and flatmapMerge is return results not in order,yes ?
is there any alternative  to RxAndroid concatMapEager ?